# Why Does @EnvironmentObject Force Re-initialization of View?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

In this example, when I drag across the screen why does `LabelViewRepresentable` get re-initialized before every "updateUIView" call? If I make the counter a `@State` property instead of an `@EnvironmentObject` property, it only initializes once like I would expect.

```swift
import SwiftUI

class Counter: ObservableObject {
  @Published var count = 0
}

struct CounterView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var counter: Counter

  var body: some View {
    LabelViewRepresentable(count: $counter.count)
      .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ _ in
        self.counter.count += 1
      }))
  }
}

struct LabelViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
  @Binding var count: Int
  private var view: UILabel

  init(count: Binding<Int>) {
    print("init")

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "0"
    self.view = label
    self._count = count
  }

  func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LabelViewRepresentable>) -> UILabel {
    print("makeUIView")
    return view
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LabelViewRepresentable>) {
    print("updateUIView")
    view.text = "\(count)"
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you call the CounterView().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at Apple docs about EnvironmentObject you will find this:

> A dynamic view property that uses a bindable object supplied by an
>   ancestor view to invalidate the current view whenever the bindable
>   object changes.

That means that each time an EnvironmentObject changes all views that are dependent on it get reinitialised and redrawn.

It works slightly different with State, in Apple docs it is described as follows:

> A persistent value of a given type, through which a view reads and
>   monitors the value.

The view cannot get reinitialised when the State changes as the State value would get discarded. The parts that are influenced by State will get redrawn. On the other hand any children of the view that have the State value passed in as a binding will get reinitialised.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this explains why the `Coordinator` is needed in a `UIViewRepresentable`. I had some properties I was storing on the `UIViewRepresentable` that were being reset because of the reinitialization, so I moved them to the coordinator which seems to persist across view updates.

Answer (score -1):

**Reason:**

- Every time you modify the data inside the `EnvironmentObject`, all the parent views that used it will get updated/redrawn, this is how SwiftUI works internally.

**Solution**

- You can use `EquatableView`
- `EquatableView` allows SwiftUI to refresh/update your View based on the rules that you defined, it's also a technique that is used to boost your app's performance since it basically restricts how each View will get updated by SwiftUI. Here is an example:

**Steps**

1. Make your subview conforms to the `Equatable` protocol

```swift
struct SubView: View, Equatable {}
```

2. Create your own rule for SwiftUI to update your subview, in this case, we have a `refreshNeeded` toggle

```swift
struct SubView: View, Equatable {
    @State private var refreshNeeded: Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var myObservable: MyObservable

    static func == (lhs: SubView, rhs: Subview) -> Bool {
        lhs.refreshNeeded == rhs.refreshNeeded
    }
}
```

3. On your parent view, wrap your subview with `EquatableView`

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
    @StateObject private var myObservable: MyObservable

    var body: some View {
        EquatableView(content: SubView())
            .environmentObject(myObservable)
    }
}
```

4. Now, if you change the data inside `EnvironmentObject`, this sub view won't get updated by SwiftUI, since `refreshNeeded` is not changed

```swift
struct SubView: View, Equatable {
    @State private var refreshNeeded: Bool = false
    @FetchRequest(...) var books: FetchedResults<Book>
    @EnvironmentObject var myObservable: MyObservable

    static func == (lhs: SubView, rhs: Subview) -> Bool {
        lhs.refreshNeeded == rhs.refreshNeeded            //<<< Set your own rule here
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(books, id: \.self) { book in 
            Text(book.name)
                .onTapGesture {
                    myObservable.bookName = book.name     //<<< This change won't affect this View now
                }
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Why not just pass it in as a “let”? Equatable for a View is just a hack used when people don’t understand how SwiftUI works.

Comment: @loremipsum I was having a bit problem with my `FetchRequest` and `EnvironmentObject`, every time I change a variable inside the `EnvironmentObject` my `FetchRequest` will reset to its initial state (with no predicate, because the View's body gets called and it needs to redraw), and I just figured out this solution which works great. Could you explain why it is a "hack"?

Comment: Because it is overriding SwiftUI’s natural behavior and will cause more issues than it fixes, if you want your FetchRequest in a specific order, add a predicate but my guess is that there is something deeper happening with your code where the identity is being overridden. SwiftUI is very specific work with it not against it. It shouldn’t be resetting the FetchRequest every time. But like I said you can just use “let”

Comment: @loremipsum I have a `ForEach` that shows the data fetched from the database, I have a search bar that basically just modifies the `FetchRequest`'s predicate, and I also have an `onTapGesture` on the data item. When I tap it, it will modify a variable inside the `EnvironmentObject` for later use. Now if I remove this code that modifies the `EnvironmentObject`, the view will not get redrawn, and my predicate will remain the same. This was my situation before, but thanks for your insight on this! I'm still kinda new to SwiftUI and I'm always learning :)